# Can someone clarify this array/pointer idea to me?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In attempt to explain that arrays are just pointers (in C++) to our class, my professor showed us this:

```
array[5]      // cout'ing this 
*(array + 5)  // would return the same value as this
```

I'm having a little trouble completely understanding it.  Here's my thinking:

`array` is the address of the first location and so if we add 5 to that address, we move 5 addresses in memory.  The pointer operator pulls the data from the memory location.

Is this the correct idea?  The idea still feels foggy with me and just feel like I don't understand it completely. I think hearing someone else explain it might help me understand it more.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first thing (array indexing) is a shorthand for the second (explicit pointer arithmetic). The second one moves a pointer 5 * `sizeof(underlying type of pointer or array)`, but it's still some address, so you need to `*` to dereference and get the real value.

Comment: @Dani Sorry if the 'question' is kind of unclear.  I realize the concept, but it's fuzzy in my mind and I was hoping that having someone else explain it would clear it up for me.

Comment: "In attempt to explain that arrays are just pointers (in C++) to our class, my professor..." ...ought to read a book. Arrays are not pointers. Please disregard your professor's most recent lecture (except to pass a test).

Comment: [relevant FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the right idea.

Arrays implicitly cast to pointers. Interestingly, `[]` works on pointers, not arrays.

a`[b]` Subscript operator is defined as `*(a + (b))`. `[]` is used as syntactic sugar - it's much more pleasant to write `array[5]` instead of `*(array + 5)`

Pointer arithmetic with a pointer and an integer `p + i` increases the address at `p` by `i * sizeof(*p)` bytes.

```
char* p; 
p + 5; // address increased by 5

int* p;
p + 5; // address increased by 20 as sizeof(*p) is 4
```

The `*` operator performs indirection. It will give you what the pointer is pointing to.

```
int x[2];
int* p = &x[0]; // could also be int* p = x;
*p = 5;         // x[0] is now 5
*(p + 1) = 10;  // x[1] is now 10
```

Comment: This is a good answer, except that `[]` is more than just syntactic sugar.  In C, this statement would be valid, but in C++ `[]` is so much more than that, thanks to operator overloading.  In C++, the index operator is defined for pointers of builtin types to be what you stated, but user defined types are free to define it as they see fit.

Comment: @MichaelPrice Good point. Although `[]` is for all pointer types, while overloading it only works on classes/unions.

Answer (score 4):

Your professor is correct that the two expressions will produce the same results. Your explanation of it leads me to believe you have a good grasp of the mechanics.

It is not quite correct to say an array is the same as a pointer. An array is very easily *converted* to a pointer, which leads to some confusion.

For example consider this code:

```
int array[5];
int * pointer = new int[5];
cout << sizeof(array);   // outputs 5*sizeof(int), most probably 20
cout << sizeof(pointer); // outputs sizeof(int*), most probably 4 on a 32 bit OS
array[4] = 906;
pointer[4] = 906;
cout << *(array + 4) << *(pointer + 4); // outputs "906 906"
```

Comment: Stated another way, it is the operations that are equivalent, not the types.

Answer (score 2):

from memory arrays in c++ are sections of continuous memory the program. thats why you can go *(array + 5) as it is 5 from the front of the array.

Also keep in mind that arrays in C++ start @ 0 so thus the 6th element in an array is array[5]
example

```
[0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] Array index
 1   2   3   4   5   6  Item number
```

To access item 2 u would either

- array[1]
- *(array+1)

but please keep in mind array[index_number] is standard syntax for looking up an item in an array so make sure u use `array[index_num]` instead of `*(array + index_num)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what your proffessor said is correct.

to explain it in detail

Consider your array,

```
int array[5]
```

here it takes 5 location in the memory say 0x00 0x04 0x08 0x0C and 0x10 0x14

Assuming integer takes 4 bytes, the locations are 4 bytes apart.

it this case 'array' represents the base address (pointer) to the array, that is 0x00. And the type of a would be int *. (since the type of the array elements is integer)

If you do array+1, it will be 0x04, since the increment of the pointer depends on the type of the pointer. If the pointer is integer, it will increment by 4 bytes. If the type of the integer is character, the pointer would increment by one bytes.

so if you do (array+5) it would point to the address 0x14 and

```
*(array+5)
```

returns the value of the location 0x14 which is the value at 5th location of array.

so in practical, array[5] is equal to *(array+5)

The compiler internally converts array[5] to  *(array+5)

so even if we write 5[array], it will get converted it to *(5+array)

Though it seems strange, this is the reason why 5[array] works same as array[5]